# Command Prompt and file explorer don't show the same folders

Tags: windows-10

When I create a folder in cmd using mkdir it doesn't show up in file explorer and vice versa. I've checked show hidden files in file explorer but still no luck. Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: Are you looking in the same directory working in cmd? If so what is it

Comment: Can you do the following.  Open a CMD prompt and change to C:\ by typing CD\ then type `mkdir testing`.  Then `cd testing` followed by `start .` Do you enter the directory in Explorer?  Can you go into the directories in Explorer or can you just not see them.  In this case can you see the `testing` directory in explorer when in C:\

Comment: Did you press F5 in the Explorer?

Comment: Ahhhhhh sorted, it was making folders in the wrong place, two of my folders were too similarly named so I was looking in one and not the other! Thanks so much both of you

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because OP indicated it was due to not spotting two similarly named directories